# Fallback background for browsers not supporting border-image

Tags: fallback, css

I'm trying to use CSS3 `border-image` for a simple button design: the left slice of the image should be the left border of the text, the right slice the right border, and the middle slice should be repeated (or stretched - it does not matter) as background. I need a fallback for browsers not supporting `border-image` - just using the middle slice as a background, without edges would be acceptable. The problem is, if I do this:

```
.button {
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-size: 0 5px;
    background: ('button-slice.png') repeat;
    border-image: url('button.png') 0 5 0 5 fill;
    -moz-border-image: url('button.png') 0 5 0 5;
    /* repeat for other vendor prefixes */
}
```

the image from the `background` property will overlap the borders and mess up the button for browsers which support `border-image`.

Is there a lightweight way of solving this problem (whithout introducing modernizr or similar javascript checks)?

Comment: The image which you are using is important. so give us that

Comment: Your average button image, a rectangle with rounded corners, on white background. I don't see why it should matter.

Comment: @Tgr had you solved your problem? Is the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

change the border-image `0 5 0 5` to `1 1 5 1` :

```
border-image: url('button.png') 1 1 5 1 fill;
-moz-border-image: url('button.png') 1 1 5 1;
```

[border-image generator online](http://border-image.com)

Comment: That messes up the button even more.

Answer (score 0):

`border-image` is tricky for fallbacks. Doing...

```
.button {
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-size: 0 5px;
    background: ('button-slice.png') repeat;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-image: url('button.png') 0 5 0 5 fill;
    -moz-border-image: url('button.png') 0 5 0 5;
    /* repeat for other vendor prefixes */
}
```

Should work for all browsers except IE9.

Since you only have a left and right border, I would suggest using pseudo-elements...

```
.button {
    border: solid 1px white;
    background: ('button-slice.png') repeat;
    position: relative;
}

.button:before, .button:after {
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent url('button.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  top: 0;
}

.button:before {left: -5px;}
.button:after {right: -5px;}
```

This technique should show nice buttons in all modern browsers plus IE8. Older browsers fallback without the edges.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that new versions of FF support both `border-image` parameters and one override another.

Try reversing the order of those lines as so:

```
-moz-border-image: url('button.png') 0 5 0 5;
border-image: url('button.png') 0 5 0 5 fill;
```

In this way, browsers that support both parameters and override one with the later will take the version with the fill.